# Htaccess 301 Redirect a sub folder with exception

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-alias

I would like to redirect to a sub-folder except a dir.

What I need is:

```
Redirect 301 /blog/ /blog-post/
#Exclude /blog/wp-admin/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `RedirectMatch`  :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/((?!wp-admin).+) /blog-post
```

This will redirect everything except `blog/wp-admin` .

If you are on apache 2.4 you can also use `Redirect` inside `if` directive

```
<if "%{REQUEST_URI} !~ m#/blog/wp-admin/#">
Redirect 301 /blog/ /blog-post/
</if>
```

Comment: Its redirecting http://example.com to http://example.com/blog-post which I don't want. Only subdirectory redirect should happen like /blog should redirect to /blog-post/

Comment: Try the updated version it should redirect **/blog/** to **/blog-post**

Comment: Thanks, I also want to exclude wp-login.php along with wp-admin?

Comment: @SnehaDagli Try the following :


  `RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/((?!wp-admin|wp-login\.php).+) /blog-post/`