# On my wordpress site I want to redirect some 404 using regex

Tags: wordpress, redirect

So, my site is set up with a /plans/ page that has links to the various /product/ pages. So a user would visit /plans/ and then click on /product/plan-a/. However, /product/ is not a page and visits to it result in a 404. Also, visits to /products/product-that-does-not-exist results in a 404.

My goal is to intercept the 404 and send these users to the /plans/ page, but only if it is a 404. If the URL is for a product that is valid, I want it to load the requested page.

So, /product/real-prodcut/ loads "Real Product" page, and /product/fake-product loads /plans/ page.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing this posted question and answer: [Htaccess 301 Redirect a sub folder with exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38157262/htaccess-301-redirect-a-sub-folder-with-exception)

You should be able to write it as such:
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/((?!real-product-1|real-product-2.php).+) /plans/